# Can't install FlightGear after upgrading to ubuntu 12

Tags: installation, upgrade, dependencies

I upgrade ubuntu to v12 and flightgear quit working. So I uninstalled it and tried the reinstall it but it will not install.
This is what happens when I try to install it.
"Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Details

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
flightgear: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
```

"
I am on 64bit system

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! here is what I did.

I had to make a dir /usr/share/games/flightgear so apt-get could remove it.
Then I sudo apt-get remove fgfs-base

I then installed flightgear via Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any extra PPA's active? Are you trying to install FlightGear from a .deb file? I was able to do a simulated install of FlightGear on my 12.04 desktop without issue just using

```
apt-get install flightgear
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the PPA's. I tryed to install from software center that is when I got to above error. I tied to sudo apt-get install flightgear and got the folowing error. " The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flightgear : Depends: fgfs-base (>= 2.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.